# Problems using uppercase names for MySQL columns with Hibernate mapping classes

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I want fix problems with uppercase names on a MySQL column of with Hibernate mapping classes. Is there a rule for use these kind of tables with Hibernate?

Comment: I didn't understand the question/problem. Could you try to clarify?

Comment: usign hibernate for mapping classes i want to know if there a rule for uppercase column names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default Hibernate will just use the field names as column names (it does not change the case).